# angularJS app with ngRoute shows a white page

Tags: angularjs

I have the following view rendered from my express server index.html

```
<section ng-view></section>
<!-- Load local libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/dummy/dummy.client.module"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dummy/dummy.client.controller"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dummy/dummy.client.route"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap AngularJS application -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/application.js"></script>
```

I manually bootstrap it with application.js file:

```
var mainApplicationModule = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'dummy'])

mainApplicationModule.config(['$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }
]);

if (window.location.hash === '#_=_') window.location.hash = '#!';

// Manually bootstrap the AngularJS application
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

Then in dummy.client.module.js:

```
angular.module('dummy', [])
```

in dummy.client.controller.js:

```
angular.module('dummy').controller('DummyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'hi what '
}])
```

dummy.client.route.js:

```
angular.module('dummy').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'dummy/dummy.client.view.html'
    })
}])
```

dummy.client.view.html:

```
<section ng-controller="DummyController">
    <textarea ng-bind="text"></textarea>
</section>
```

I get an empty page. the controller is not invoked (i use alert('hi') to test)
If i don't use ngRoute, i.e. append all the js files in the index.html page, it's working instead of using ngRoute and ng-view, it works

error message:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module dummy due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'dummy' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-build.3042+sha.76e57a7/$injector/nomod?p0=dummy
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:120:12
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:215:17
    at ensure (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:139:38)
    at module (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:213:14)
    at angular.module (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:686:31)
    at angular.module (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1019:38)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3877:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3871:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3878:40
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=dummy&p1=Error%3A%…t%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3878%3A40
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3905:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3871:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3878:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3871:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3811:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:1444:20)
    at Object.angular.resumeBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:1467:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…p%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1467%3A5)angular.js:78 (anonymous function)angular.js:3905 (anonymous function)angular.js:325 forEachangular.js:3871 loadModulesangular.js:3811 createInjectorangular.js:1444 doBootstrapangular.js:1467 angular.resumeBootstraphint.js:535 maybeBootstrap
```

[Edit]:

I have tried another module and still not working: 
article.client.module.js:

```
angular.module('article', [])
```

article.client.route.js:

```
angular.module('article').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl:'article/list-article.client.view.html'})
    }
]);
```

article.client.controller:

```
angular.module('article').controller('ArticleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.text = 'hi'
    }
])
```

list-article.client.view.html:

```
<section ng-controller="ArticleController">
    <textarea ng-bind="text"></textarea>
</section>
```

application.js:

```
//var mainApplicationModule = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'dummy']);
var mainApplicationModule = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'article']);
//var mainApplicationModule = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'article', 'user', 'index']);

mainApplicationModule.config(['$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }
]);

if (window.location.hash === '#_=_') window.location.hash = '#!';

// Manually bootstrap the AngularJS application
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

```
<section ng-view></section>
<!-- Load local libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/dummy/dummy.client.module.js"></script>-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/dummy/dummy.client.controller.js"></script>-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/dummy/dummy.client.route.js"></script>-->


<!-- Load the articles module -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/article/article.client.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/article/article.client.controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/article/article.client.route.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/article/article.client.resource.js"></script>-->

<!-- Bootstrap AngularJS application -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/application.js"></script>
```

I commented out the dummy module. same error as before

[Edit 2]:

if i change the folder name to article2 or anything other than 'article', then it works.

Comment: Did you get any error message like 404 of resource in console?

Comment: Syntax error may also cause such issue!

Comment: did you put ng-app="dummy" into your html somewhere?

Comment: You have `app` and `dummy` so what are you using for `ng-app`?

Comment: @tommyd456 I use manual bootstrap, so I don't use ng-app

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing `.js` in the script include. Because of which `dummy` module is failed to initialize and consequently you get the mentioned error.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/dummy/dummy.client.module.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/dummy/dummy.client.controller.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/dummy/dummy.client.route.js"></script>
```

extended answer to extended question...
Now, there are two more problems here

1. `article` module is getting initialized as you are using `ngRouteProvider` in `article` module without adding `ngRoute` dependency.

   //You need to add ngRoute dependency in order to use $ngRouteProvider
   angular.module('article', ['ngRoute']);

for this you also need to include `angular-route.js`
refer : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

2. You are using `ngResource` in `application.js` but I do not see you are including `angular-resource.js`

refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

Comment: the dummy client module worked with .js. but article is exactly the same. I don't see any error

Comment: sorry the ng-reousrce and route library are included. it's the same as the dummy module

Comment: i don't need the ngRoute for article, the same reason i don't need it for dummy

Comment: if i change the folder name to article2 or anything other than 'article', then it works.

Comment: maybe it's because of any naming conflict?

Comment: modify this plnkr as per your requirement and let me know the result.

Comment: can you create a folder 'article' and put article relevant files inside?

Comment: btw, it still works when you remove the ngRoute, as long as it's inside the appplication.js file